# User Notifications and Upstream Messages - how to not to show dismissed notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

got a question about User Notifications and Upstream Messages features.

Suppose user has 2 devices: device A and device B.
Device A is online and **device B is offline**.
Third party server is sending X notifications to the notification key.
Device A receives all of the notifications. User dismisses all of them and device A sends X notification to GCM (one notification sent per one notification received) that the notification was dismissed.
Now device B goes online and receives X + X notifications - X notifications sent by a third party server and X notifications sent by the device A with dismiss information. As a result X notifications are shown and right after that dismissed on device B.

How do you handle such situations?
How to not to show dismissed notifications?

Answer (score 0):

When a user dismisses a notification on their device,send a note to the server to delete that notification for that user. That way when a new device polls for notifications, the dismissed notification won't show up.

If you have another case where both devices are connected to the internet, and one dismisses a notification, because that device sent a message to the server saying the notification was dismissed, the server should now send messages to all the user's devices saying to remove the notification if it exists.

Comment: How to send a note to the GCM to delete a particular notification from its cloud?

Comment: That you'll have to figure out because I've never worked with GCM before, but I think what I've said could be a reasonable solution